# Bash For loop change back to original directory before next iteration

Tags: bash

I have a for loop that lists all the subdirectories which works fine, but I want to enter each directory, run a command then move onto the next directory but it just stays in the first directory it enters.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls -l ../terraform/envs/ | grep ^d | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9 );
  do
    echo $i | awk -v i="$i" !'/maint|template/'
    cd ../terraform/envs//$i
    echo $PWD
    break
    #terragrunt plan
done
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

Use `pushd` instead of `cd`; then you can use `popd` to return to the original directory.

Unrelated, but there's no need to use `ls` like this. Use a glob instead.

```
cd terraform/envs
for i in */; do
    pushd "$i" > /dev/null
    echo "$PWD"
    popd > /dev/null
done
```

(Of course, here, the `cd` command before the loop means you can just use `cd "$i"` and `cd ..`, but `pushd`/`popd` work well for arbitrary directory changes, not just simple one-step-down-and-back.)

(Note that if you use `pushd` more than once, you'll need to pass an appropriate argument to `popd` to ensure you return to the right stack entry, or call `popd` an appropriate number of times.)

Comment: Yep, `pushd` and `popd` don't get the use they should. Of course it's also useful to let those learning know they can redirect to `/dev/null` to suppress the output (you would be surprised to know just how many don't snap to that....) E.g. `pushd "$i" > /dev/null` and the same following `popd`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to answer your question, you can go back to the previous directory thanks to the `cd -` command. It will print out the directory you came back to. If you don’t want that output, redirect to `/dev/null`, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls -l ../terraform/envs/ | grep ^d | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9 );
  do
    echo $i | awk -v i="$i" !'/maint|template/'
    cd ../terraform/envs//$i
    echo $PWD
    cd - > /dev/null
    break
    #terragrunt plan
done
```

Also, as @Cyrus mentioned, parsing the `ls` output is usually a bad idea. There are many alternatives, I would recommend reading the variable from `find`, e.g.:

```
while read i;
  do
  # do something
done < <(find ../terraform/envs/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

And at last, but not least, you should put your variables into quotes as often as possible, e.g. in `echo` and `cd`, like you did for `awk`.

All in all you should get something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read i;
  do
    echo "$i" | awk -v i="$i" !'/maint|template/'
    cd "../terraform/envs//$i"
    echo $PWD
    cd - > /dev/null
    break
    #terragrunt plan
done < <(find ../terraform/envs/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

Comment: Also, `cd -` only does what you want if there are no other `cd` commands in between. Otherwise, you need to explicitly remember the working directory before the first `cd` command in order to restore it at the end.

Comment: @chepner in the example I mentioned, what cases won’t work?

Comment: @chepner `cd -` should be just fine for what he suggested  AFAIK

Comment: I seriously doubt `echo $PWD` is the entire code to be executed in the new directory. `cd -` might work, but it's impossible to say without knowing what actually gets executed after changing directories.

Comment: The proper way to use `pushd`/`popd` is to *always* have a matched pair in your own code.